# Replace Cordova Developed App with Native Android App

Tags: android, cordova

I Have a query
I have an app on the Google Play store since long and it was developed using Cordova
Now I have made a separate APK using Native Android (Android Studio)
I have 1000 downloads!
I want to replace the new Native built Apk with the old Cordova
without losing any downloads or review & ratings

How can I Do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as it is the same keystore and package name, you don't have to worry.

Simply create a new Android Studio project (or in whatever IDE you use) and make sure the **package name is the same as the previous one**. You can change it after the project is generated, but it is harder than making sure it is right.

After you generate the project, write the code.

After you write the app finished, just upload it with a higher version code than the current one (just like normal). **Make sure it is signed with the same keystore and has the same package name** and you can update it running different code

---

AS you already have the code (or so is my understanding) make sure the package name is the same, the version is higher than the previous upload and it is signed with the same keystore. Upload and you are good to go